# How to route Vitepress app to sub-route of main app with Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, vite, vitepress

I'm trying to set up a documentation for our app on the same domain, using Vitepress. Locally, I can run our app on port `5173` and the Vitepress documentation on port `9000`. We're using following Docker containers to run our app (frontend only):

```
1. nginx
2. vite
3. vitepress (documentation)
```

How can I set up docker to route the `9000` port to sub-route `/docs/` of our domain? Locally the docs should be available at: `https://localhost:5173/docs/`.

I've tried lots of things but always end up running into an `502` error. Following setup is before described routing is attempted.

#### Docker containers:

`/docker/nginx/conf.d/local.conf`:

```
...

location /docs/ {
  proxy_pass http://vitepress:9000/;
}

...
```

`/docker/vite/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16

EXPOSE 5173

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ADD docker/vite/cmd/startnode startnode

RUN install -m 0755 startnode /usr/local/bin

CMD startnode
```

`/docker/vite/cmd/startnode`:

```
yarn
yarn dev
```

`/docker/vitepress/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16

EXPOSE 9000

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ADD docker/vitepress/cmd/startnode startnode

RUN install -m 0755 startnode /usr/local/bin

CMD startnode
```

`/docker/vitepress/cmd/startnode`:

```
yarn
yarn vp
```

`/docker/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      # 5173 is the port exposed to the Docker Host
      # 443 is the port other bridged Docker Container can access the Service
      - '5173:443'
    volumes:
      - '..:/var/www/html:delegated'
      - 'trinity-ui-vite-mnt:/var/run'
    networks:
      trinity-ui-vite-bridge:
        aliases:
          - trinity-ui-vite.local
  vite:
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/vite/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '..:/var/www/html:delegated'
      - 'trinity-ui-vite-mnt:/var/run'
    networks:
      trinity-ui-vite-bridge:
        aliases:
          - trinity-ui-vite.local
  vitepress:
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/vitepress/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - '..:/var/www/html:delegated'
      - 'trinity-ui-vite-mnt:/var/run'
    networks:
      trinity-ui-vite-bridge:
        aliases:
          - trinity-ui-vite.local

networks:
  trinity-ui-vite-bridge: null
volumes:
  trinity-ui-vite-mnt: null
```

`/docker/start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "${1}" == "--rebuild" ]]
then
    docker-compose -p tuiv up --build -d
else
    result=$( docker images -q tuiv-vite )

    if [[ -n "$result" ]]; then
        docker-compose -p tuiv start
    else
        docker-compose -p tuiv up --build -d
        docker network connect tuiv_trinity-ui-vite-bridge ft-nginx-1
    fi
fi
```

`/docs/.vitepress/vitepress.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  base: '/docs/',
};
```

these are the relevant scripts in `package.json`:

```
"docs:dev": "vitepress dev docs --port=9000 --base=/docs/ --host",
"docs:build": "vitepress build docs",
"docs:serve": "vitepress serve docs",
"docgen": "vue-docgen -c docgen.config.mjs",
"docs": "vue-docgen -w -c docgen.config.mjs",
"vp": "yarn run docs:dev"
```

With this setup, docker starts vitepress on `http://localhost:9000/docs/` and our main app on `https://localhost:5173`. How would one make the docs available on `https://localhost:5173/docs/`?

I've tried using different configurations (nginx/conf.d/local.conf):

```
location /docs/ {
  proxy_pass http://vitepress:5173/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_buffering off;
}
```

but then I run into the `502`. The `nginx` container log shows:

```
2023-11-30 15:17:53 2023/11/30 15:17:53 [error] 29#29: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.65.1, server: _, request: "GET /docs/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:9000/", host: "localhost:5173"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vitepress app is running on port `9000` within its container, but the NGINX proxy setup is trying to route to port `5173`?!

Make sure the [`base` URL in your Vitepress configuration](https://vitepress.dev/reference/site-config#base) (`/docs/.vitepress/vitepress.config.js`) is correctly set to `/docs/`. That would make Vitepress aware that it is being served from a subpath.

```js
module.exports = {
  base: '/docs/',
  // ... other configurations
};
```

Make sure there is no redirect (`rewrite` or `return` directives) in your NGINX configuration causing a loop. And use the `proxy_pass` directive without a trailing slash if you are including the `/docs/` path in the proxy_pass URL.
A `proxy_redirect off;` does not seem to be needed.

```
location /docs/ {
    proxy_pass http://vitepress:9000;  # No trailing slash
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Clear your browser's cache or try incognito mode. Redirect loops can sometimes be caused by caching issues.
Then check the NGINX container logs for any errors or clues about why the redirects are happening.
And use browser developer tools to inspect network traffic: look at the response headers for the requests to `https://localhost:5173/docs/` to see where the redirects are coming from.

```bash
+---------+      +--------+      +-----------+
|         |      |        |      |           |
|  NGINX  +----->+  VITE  |      | VITEPRESS |
|         |      |        |      |           |
+----+----+      +--------+      +-----+-----+
     |                                |
     |       Proxy /docs/ to port 9000|
     +------------------------------->+
```

Comment: with your code vitepress works on `http://localhost:9000/docs/` but `https://localhost:5173/docs/` shows `this page isn't working - localhost redirected to many times` while `https://localhost:5173/docs` shows `this site can't be reached - localhost refused to connect`

Comment: the network tab of the browser shows redirect spam to `/docs` sub-route

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov I have rewritten the answer to address those points.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Great, well done! Does it work also without the `proxy_redirect off;`?

Comment: yes, that's the first thing I tried to check. It really is the trailing slash. I've excluded it in past iterations but it seems my configuration was not right back then. Now everything works. Thanks so much

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov OK, so I can remove that directive from the answer, then?